# MySQL database replication not working - show processlist db is null

Tags: mysql, database-replication

The replication between my 2 MySQL databases wont start the replication... I have a problem with the time that is in a different timezone than the other database server could it be the timezone difference?...

They both have different server ID's... I told the slave to look into the masters correct log position file...

I follow this thread: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-master-slave-replication-in-mysql

Master DB: [image: The master DB]

Show processlist... The db says null?
[image]

Slave DB: [image: The Slave DB]

Comment: Whenever possible please post plain text, not screenshots. These pictures aren't searchable.

Comment: Timezone should not be a problem as mysql binlog sets timestamp before each statement. Does not your show processlist list anything ?

Comment: I just uploaded a image of the processlist on the master DB :)

Comment: Sorry - It is working... I thought it did catch up with the current data in my database.... Of course it is only aware of whats in the log file! It is working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - It is working... I thought it did catch up with the current data in my database.... Of course it is only aware of whats in the log file! It is working!